# Under what condition on matrix $Q$ we have $tr(AQ)=tr(BQ)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, random-matrices

Let $A,B$ are similar matrices. Then, under what condition on matrix $Q$, we have $tr(AQ)=tr(BQ)$

$A$ and $B$ are similar matrices, so there exist an invertible matrix $P$ such that $$A=P^{-1}BP\\
AQ=P^{-1}BPQ\quad \text {(taking  $Q$ invertible matrix)}\\
tr(AQ)=tr(P^{-1}BPQ)$$ But unable to reach at result.What will happen if $Q$ is singular matrix?

I know that similar matrices have same eigenvalues but not getting a way to use this. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: $\operatorname{tr}(AQ)=\operatorname{tr}(P^{-1}BPQ)=\operatorname{tr}(BPQP^{-1})$, so it's sufficient that $PQP^{-1}=Q$, i.e. that $Q$ commutes with $P$. Are you looking for a necessary condition?

Comment: @joriki Yes Sir, I'm looking for a necessary condition.

Answer (score 2):

The linear functional $\phi: Q \mapsto \text{tr}(AQ) - \text{tr}(BQ)$ on $n \times n$ matrices is nonzero if $A \ne B$, and so those $Q$ for which $\phi(Q) = 0$ form a linear subspace of the $n \times n$ matrices with codimension $1$.  For any $n \times n$ matrix $X$, there is a scalar $z$ such that $X + z (A-B)^*$ is in this subspace.  Here ${}^*$ denotes the [Hermitian transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) (or the transpose in the real case).

Answer (score 2):

$\def\tr#1{\operatorname{tr}\left(#1\right)}\tr{AQ}=\tr{BQ}$ is equivalent to $\tr{(A-B)Q}=0$. Thus the equality holds for all $Q$ in the orthogonal complement of $(A-B)^\top$ with respect to the [Frobenius product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product). For $n\times n$ matrices, this has dimension $n^2-1$ (except if $A=B$).

Comment: Sir Suppose Frobenius product, Hadamard product are not in syllabus, then is there any way to find the condition?

Comment: @Chiranjeev_Kumar: Orthogonality with respect to the Frobenius product is just a convenient way to express the solution space of the linear equation. If you don't know about the product, you still have $\tr{(A-B)Q}=0$ as a linear equation in $n^2$ variables, which has a solution space of $n^2-1$ dimensions (unless $A-B=0$). There isn't more to it than that.

Comment: Thanx for your valuable reply :) . Frobenius product, Hadamard product are not difficult to understand but these things are not in syllabus so we can't use in answering the question. That's why I asked that.